# Behavior of universal-argument (C-u) changed between org 9.1.9 and org 9.4?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, prefix-argument

Running org version 9.1.9, when invoking `C-u C-c C-t` (`org-agenda-todo`) I get a completion list of my status values that I can select from.

In org version 9.4 the same call no longer allows me to select a status, it simply cycles to the next status value on my status values list. The `C-c C-t` keybinding still invokes `org-agenda-todo` so that leads me to think that the behavior of `C-u` has changed as applied to that function. I can invoke `C-u <number> C-c C-t` to get the desired status but then I have to remember the number for each of my status values.

How can I make org 9.4 resume that desired 9.1.9 behavior?

Comment: Did you define keys for the status? E.g. `#+TODO: TODO(n) NEXT(n) | DONE(d)`?

Comment: No, but I use `!` and `@`. `#+TODO: TODO(!) STARTED(!) WAITING(@)...`